# How can I set up a PXE-Boot server on DD-WRT?

Tags: dd-wrt, pxe

At home I have a Cisco/Linksys E1000 flashed to DD-WRT (v24-sp2 (04/13/11) mini) and am trying to set it up as a PXE Boot server. There seems to be some info in the DD-WRT wiki which is slighty out of date. I think I've got to set something up under Services > Services > DNSmasq but as for what I'm a bit stuck.

I have:

- E1000 router running DDWRT with only the default admin password and the SSID changed (so basically a "vanilla" setup.) on 192.168.1.1 and serving DHCP requests.
- A Home File server running TFTP32 with an IP of 192.168.1.2
- A (number of) PXE-bootable machines
- Time

Once this is done, is there an "easy" way to tell if the PXE-boot option is avalible for machine, or do I need to go through the whole "making a boot image" as well, again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dnsmasq can be used as a boot server. It can even function as the TFTP server too.

Go to the the Dnsmasq setting page. Enter this in the 
Additional DHCPd Options:
`dhcp-boot=pxeimage,fileserver,192.168.1.2`

(enter the routers name and ip instead if you want the router to host the pxeimage)

Comment: I didn't know the router could be set up as the TFTP server, I'll look into that, thanks.